# shell with django environment in eclipse,pydev giving syntax error

Tags: python, django, eclipse, shell, pydev

```
``>>>python manage.py syncdb  

 File "<console>", line 1  
python manage.py syncdb
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  
            ^``
```

What could the problem be?

Extra Info if it might help -
Python  - 2.6
Django  - 1.2.5
Eclipse - 3.6.0
Pydev   - 1.6.5

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, @chris is right, your trying to run a file with a Python interpreter from within an interactive shell.

If you add Django (`org.python.pydev.django.djangoNature`) to the list of your project natures, you can then right click on your project in the resources view and you then have the Django submenu from where you can run a custom `manage.py` command and other commands such as `sycdb`, `test`, etc. from the list of entries.

If you want to store a custom command which would be an equivalent to, say, `manage.py test myapp1, myapp2` you then create a custom run configuration. Basically, you specify your current project as the "Project", `manage.py` as the "Main module" and then write "test myapp1, myapp2" as the argument for `manage.py`.